# Checking with DynamoDB that another row exists?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's say that I have an item `PK=foo` and `SK=bar`. What the item contains is not relevant. How can I check when inserting *another* item that this particular item exists? In this case both items would have the same partition key.

Comment: Use a conditional [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) request to add a new item if one with the specified primary key doesn't exist. But ... your question suggests that you want to prevent another item if both items would have the same partition key. Did you mean same "partition key" (so ignoring the sort key)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using DynamoDB Transactions. Use the PutItem for the write and the ConditionCheck for the existence of a second item.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html